# Soundcloud API Play and Pause button

Tags: javascript, soundcloud

I am making a website using SoundCloud API and i'm getting sounds and everything.

```
SC.oEmbed('https://soundcloud.com/mustafa-shorish/bandeya-ho-khuda-kay-liye',  {
element: document.getElementById('putTheWidgetHere') });
```

Everything is working great except I want to add a play/pause button to control the sound. I saw some examples but only with iframe which using Widget API. Here's my code for play pause button.

```
var widget = SC.Widget("putTheWidgetHere"); 
$(function(){
$("#playSound").click(function() {
    widget.play();

});

$("#stopSound").click(function() {
    widget.pause()
});
});
```

But it keeps saying that SC.Widget is not a function. Can someone please help me?

Comment: Could you provide us with a jsfiddle?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply but I've solved my problem.